# What is the best way to query ALL subscribers?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-views

We're using an enterprise 2.0 account, and are querying from the parent BU.

What we're confused about is which data view should we query to receive an accurate report on ALL the 'Subscribers' in our account?

We're finding differences when we query _Subscribers and _ListSubscribers (where the ListID = 1670 [ID of AllSubscribers])

what further confuses us is that we've found a bunch of subscribers who don't show up when we do a search for them on AllSubscribers - which contradicts the logic that AllSubscribers is the master table of the account.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: one small note - "AllSubscribers is the master table of the account"  - that is not the case. You can be a Contact without being a Subscriber (on All Subscribers). Someone went through the details here: https://deselect.io/salesforce-marketing-cloud-data-model-part-3-how-to-manage-data-in-contact-builder/

Comment: Thank you @JonasLamberty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

_ListSubscribers and _Subscribers are very similar when querying the Admin Business Unit/"ENT" Schema. You'll potentially find subscribers of type other than 0 ("ExactTarget") in your _Subscribers view, however, that don't appear in All Subscribers/List Subscribers. This will be particularly true if you're using one of the connectors for Salesforce CRM or Microsoft Dynamics or you're making use of triggered sends where you choose not to update All Subscribers in the Triggered Send Definition. In these instances, SFMC maintains "hidden" lists of Subscribers that you can't view in All Subscribers and aren't included in the _ListSubscribers records for the All Subscribers list.

Comment: Thank you Macca! Super useful. We use marketing cloud connect, so what you're saying about the 'other' subscribers makes sense. We've got 2 further questions here @Macca : 1) If you were undertaking a contact deletion process to clean up, where would you delete from:? ) And we've got a strange case where we found a bunch of subscribers on the _Subscribers table, but didn't show up when we searched using the 'All subscriber' search UI. Would that be because of what you've mentioned? Or could there be other reasons? Thanks for your help!